# Need to create Jenkins job with extended choice parameter to achieve dynamic parameter section using groovy script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, parameters, stack

Name is indirect and direct application will be shown in section shell script or pipeline

Comment: You can use Parameterized Pipeline, check this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: It is not useful, is there any other solution with groovy script.Need to differentiate similar parameters in all Jenkin jobs and display only remaining parameters. If we select any stack name it display only remaining parameters.